# Ansible - community.mysql python module errors

Tags: mysql, ansible, python

I am trying to use Ansibles community msql modules to setup an external database. However, I get the following error message when I try to create a database:

```
failed: [target] (item=db_name) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "db_name", "msg": "A MySQL module is required: for Python 2.7 either PyMySQL, or MySQL-python, or for Python 3.X mysqlclient or PyMySQL. Consider setting ansible_python_interpreter to use the intended Python version."}
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error as I have the mysqlclient and PyMySQL modules installed on the host machine. Here is some information about the versions that I use:

```
vagrant@ctrl-01:~$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.16.1]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/vagrant/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/vagrant/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True


vagrant@ctrl-01:~$ pip list |grep -i sql
mysqlclient            2.1.1
PyMySQL                1.1.0

vagrant@ctrl-01:~$ ansible-galaxy collection list | grep mysql
community.mysql               3.8.0
```

I could not find additional requirements for the mysql module so I am a bit at a loss here.

EDIT:

Since it has been mentioned in a reply:
The mysql and mysqldump binaries and the PyMySQL module are also present at the target host:

```
[root@galera01-rhel8 ~]# which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
[root@galera01-rhel8 ~]# which mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysqldump


[root@galera01-rhel8 ~]# pip3 list | grep -i sql
PyMySQL      0.10.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try to change the ansible.cfg to set the default interpreter of Python on the remote server,

```
interpreter_python  = /usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install one of the required modules on the target machine, where the action is executed.

Quote from [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_db_module.html#notes) (highlight by me):

> - Requires the mysql and mysqldump binaries **on the remote host**.
> - Requires the PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python 3.X) or MySQL-python (Python 2.X) package installed **on the remote host**.

Comment: These binaries are present on the target machine. I will edit the question to make that more clear, though. Thank you.

Comment: And the Python packages?

Comment: While I initially was missing them on the host machine, I installed them after your reply. However, I still encounter the same error messages. Updated the question to reflect that.